# Why is this boolean expression false?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression

When I run

```
boolean a = false;
boolean b = false;
boolean result = (a && (b || !a)) == a && b;
System.out.println(result);
```

I get false in Java. Why? This is equivalent to false == false, which is true. This is not Java specific, I get the same result in other languages, too. Is this because of short circuit evaluation? It seems like the left and right would/should still get compared.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to `false == false`, it's equivalent to `true && false` because of the operator precendence `( (a && (b || !a)) == a ) && b`

Comment: a && (b || !a) is false. && always short circuits. then false == false is true, then true && false is false. So I would expect false.

Answer (score 0):

The comment was the answer. `==` has the highest precedence and will be evaluated first, with the left being `a && (b || !a)` and the right being `a`.